# Redirecting as well as opening a new window

Tags: asp.net

I have a Save button in a page, where in after successful execution, i need to redirect it to Successful Page and at the same time, need to open another window, using javascript

I m able to either open a new window or redirect the page

```
save(){
    //Some code here
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "js", "window.open('http:/xyz.com');", true);
    Response.redirect("abc.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "a", "window.open('http:/xyz.com');", true);
Response.Redirect("abc.aspx");
```

Comment: you have to write double / in url.

Comment: "window.open('http:/xyz.com');window.location.href='abc.aspx'"